# Can't display image even though it's in the same folder

Tags: image, angular, path, webpack, src

Here's my angular component, I'm trying to get an image to display (later I want to implement it dynamically but I cant even get it to work by hardcoding img src)

As you can see in my image, both files are in the same folder `contents`

content-list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Content } from './content.model';
import { ContentService } from './content.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-content-list',
    template: `
        <div class="contrainer col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div *ngFor="let content of contents">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{ content.file }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src="my.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Can't Display Image" width="304" height="236" />
        </div>
    `,
    styles:[`
    `]
})

export class ContentListComponent implements OnInit {
    contents: Content[];

    constructor(private contentService: ContentService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.contentService.getMessages()
            .subscribe(
                (contents: Content[]) => {
                    this.contents = contents
                }
            );
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! It had to do with webpack image loader

I set my webpack.config.common.js to the following:

```
test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                    loaders: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]', {
                    loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                    query: {
                        mozjpeg: {
                            progressive: true,
                        },
                        gifsicle: {
                            interlaced: false,
                        },
                        optipng: {
                            optimizationLevel: 4,
                        },
                        pngquant: {
                            quality: '75-90',
                            speed: 3,
                        },
                    },
                }],
```

And to reference an image I have to use `js/app/image_path`

for example:

```
imageURL = "/js/app/my.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

The `src` path of the image you are trying to dispaly should be relative to the HTML page that displays it, **not** to the template or the `.ts` file.

Therefore, you need to change the image `src` to include a specific path according to the HTML that contains it. Something like:

```
<img src="/content/my.jpg" ... >
```

Comment: The html that ends up using the template is actually `content-list.component.html` which is in the same directory.

Comment: Using the browser's developer console, when you examine the broken image, what path do you see ?

Comment: That's the problem I was mentioning. It should be `http://localhost3000/content/my.jpg`

Comment: I just tried `<img src="http://localhost3000/assets/app/contents/my.jpg" />` and it still doesn't work. my directory goes like this root >> assets >> app >> contents >> my.jpg

Comment: Are you sure it's `localhost3000`? Not `localhost:3000` ?

Comment: Good observation but still not working, here's the img tag copy pasted from my code `<img src="http://localhost:3000/assets/app/contents/my.jpg" />`

Comment: Try this: `<img src="/assets/app/contents/my.jpg" />`

Comment: Are you sure the image is there??

Comment: After the latest change, did you try refreshing the page after deleting cached files ?

Comment: Yes and yes, I'm using Webstorm IDE and it even detects the image automatically.

Comment: After the latest change, What is the image `src` if you view the page source in the browser ?

Comment: I updated my question with an image directly from my console, I'm suspicious of the `_ngcontent_afj-1` attribute in my img.

Comment: Yep, That can't be right. Where is that coming from ?

Comment: Is that something auto generated? Also, did you try removing the `class` arrtibute from your image ?

Comment: It is autogenerated since every element in my component seems to have it and yes, I only have the src attribute in my img tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141494/discussion-between-koby-douek-and-ysa).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<img src="./my.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Can't Display Image" width="304" height="236" />
```